# How to find the difference in days between two dates?

Tags: bash, shell, date

A="2002-20-10"
B="2003-22-11"

How to find the difference in days between two dates?

Comment: As explained below, but your dates are the wrong way round: they need to be yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Many answers use the -d option of (GNU-)date. I want to add that this is NOT a part of POSIX date, therefore less portable. 
As long as the OP is not working on Unix distributions like Solaris, but only "common Linux", he or she should be good tho. A respective tag would help imho.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you have GNU `date`, it allows to print the representation of an arbitrary date (`-d` option).
In this case convert the dates to seconds since EPOCH, subtract and divide by 24*3600.

Example using GNU date (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9008871/215713):

```sh
let DIFF=($(date +%s -d 20210131)-$(date +%s -d 20210101))/86400
echo $DIFF
30
```

This also works with dates in other formats, for example "2021-01-31".

Other answers suggest ways to do it that don't require GNU date.

Comment: @Tree: I believe there is no portable way to subtract dates short of implementing it yourself — it's not that hard, the only thing of interest are leap years. But nowadays everyone wants to subtract dates, as it seems: Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/tool-in-unix-to-subtract-dates :)

Comment: For lazyweb's sake, I think this is what user332325 meant: ```echo "( `date -d $B +%s` - `date -d $A +%s`) / (24*3600)" | bc -l ```

Comment: What does portable mean in this context?

Comment: @htellez something that works on multiple platforms (windows, linux etc..)

Comment: For bash one liner based on this answer see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49728059/1485527

Comment: @Sumudu and @ htellez I think, user332325 means that the `-d` option of (GNU-)`date` is NOT a part of POSIX date, therefore less portable. 
As long as the OP is not working on Unix distributions like Solaris, but only "common Linux", this works. If not, check user332325's link above!

@ jschnasse's answer also uses `date -d`

Comment: This answer does not work on macOS in Bash 5.1: `date: illegal time format [...] bash: let: DIFF=(-)/86400: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ")/86400")`

Answer (score 87):

The bash way - convert the dates into %y%m%d format and then you can do this straight from the command line:

```
echo $(( ($(date --date="031122" +%s) - $(date --date="021020" +%s) )/(60*60*24) ))
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily need the dates to be in `%y%m%d` format.  E.g. gnu date will accept the `%Y-%m-%d` format the OP used.  In general, ISO-8601 is a good choice (and the OP's format is one such format).  Formats with 2 digit years are better avoided.

Comment: For the difference from **today**, one may like to use `days_diff=$(( (\`date -d $B +%s\` - \`date -d "00:00" +%s\`) / (24*3600) ))`. note that `$days_diff` will be an integer (i.e. no decimals)

Comment: This is dependent on the variant of `date` installed.  It works for GNU `date`.  It doesn't work with POSIX `date`.  This probably isn't a problem for most readers, but it's worth noting.

Comment: If you really want POSIX portability, check this:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7220/43835

Comment: Just to combat confusion: OP's format is **not** `%Y-%m-%d`, until we introduce `August 2.0` and `October 2.0` OP's format is `%Y-%d-%m`. Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: This answer does not work on macOS with Bash 5.1: `date: illegal option -- - [...] bash: ( -  )/(60*60*24) : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ")/(60*60*24) ")`

Comment: On 32 bit Linux, this does not work for dates > Epochalypse.

Answer (score 35):

**tl;dr**

```sh
date_diff=$(( ($(date -d "2015-03-11 UTC" +%s) - $(date -d "2015-03-05 UTC" +%s)) / (60*60*24) ))
```

Watch out! Many of the bash solutions here are broken for date ranges which span the date when daylight savings time begins (where applicable). This is because the $(( math )) construct does a 'floor'/truncation operation on the resulting value, returning only the whole number. Let me illustrate:

DST started March 8th this year in the US, so let's use a date range spanning that:

```
start_ts=$(date -d "2015-03-05" '+%s')
end_ts=$(date -d "2015-03-11" '+%s')
```

Let's see what we get with the double parentheses:

```
echo $(( ( end_ts - start_ts )/(60*60*24) ))
```

Returns '5'.

Doing this using 'bc' with more accuracy gives us a different result:

```
echo "scale=2; ( $end_ts - $start_ts )/(60*60*24)" | bc
```

Returns '5.95' - the missing 0.05 being the lost hour from the DST switchover.

So how should this be done correctly?
I would suggest using this instead:

```
printf "%.0f" $(echo "scale=2; ( $end_ts - $start_ts )/(60*60*24)" | bc)
```

Here, the 'printf' rounds the more accurate result calculated by 'bc', giving us the correct date range of '6'.

Edit: highlighting the answer in a comment from @hank-schultz below, which I have been using lately:

```
date_diff=$(( ($(date -d "2015-03-11 UTC" +%s) - $(date -d "2015-03-05 UTC" +%s) )/(60*60*24) ))
```

This should also be leap second safe as long as you always subtract the earlier date from the later one, since leap seconds will only ever add to the difference - truncation effectively rounds down to the correct result.

Comment: If instead, you specify the timezone for both the start and the end (and make sure they are the same), then you also no longer have this problem, like so:

`echo $(( ($(date --date="2015-03-11 UTC" +%s) - $(date --date="2015-03-05 UTC" +%s) )/(60*60*24) ))`, which returns 6, instead of 5.

Comment: Ah, one of the answerers thought about the inaccuracies of the basic solution repeated by others in variants. Thumbs up! How about leap seconds? It is leap-second-safe? There are precedents of software returning off-by-one-**day** result if run at certain times, ref [problems associated with the leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second#Examples_of_problems_associated_with_the_leap_second).

Comment: Woops, the "wrong" computation you give as example correctly returns 6 here (Ubuntu 15.04 AMD64, GNU date version 8.23). Perhaps your example is timezone-dependant? My timezone is "Europe/Paris".

Comment: Same good result for the "wrong" computation with GNU date 2.0 on MSYS, same timezone.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon, your timezone's daylight savings change looks to have happened on March 29, 2015 - so try a date range which includes that.

Comment: @evan_b you're right. Replacing 11 with 30 yields 24 days with integer arithmetic, 24.95 with bc, and an error with printf because locale uses a comma for decimal separator instead of dot. Prefixing with `LC_ALL=C` (with bash, might be different with other shells) yields the correct number 25.

Comment: This answer does not work on macOS with Bash 5.1: `bash: ( - ) / (60*60*24) : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ") / (60*60*24) ")`

Answer (score 21):

And in python

```
$python -c "from datetime import date; print (date(2003,11,22)-date(2002,10,20)).days"
398
```

Comment: @mouviciel not really.  Python is not always present.

Comment: @mc0e in that context, nothing is always present

Comment: @Anubis the OP specified tags as `bash` and `shell`, so I think we can assume that we're talking about a *nix system.  Within such systems, `echo` and `date` are reliably present, but python is not.

Comment: @mc0e yeah that makes sense. Even-though python2 is available in most *nix systems, when it comes to low-end devices (embedded etc..) we will have to survive only with primary tools.

Answer (score 20):

This works for me:

```
A="2002-10-20"
B="2003-11-22"
echo $(( ($(date -d $B +%s) - $(date -d $A +%s)) / 86400 )) days
```

Prints

```
398 days
```

**What is happening?**

1. Provide valid time string in **A** and **B**
2. Use `date -d` to handle time strings
3. Use `date %s` to convert time strings to seconds since 1970 (unix epoche)
4. Use [bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to subtract seconds
5. divide by seconds per day (86400=60*60*24) to get difference as days
6. ! [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is not taken into account ! See this answer at [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/quickly-calculate-date-differences)!

Comment: This answer does not work on macOS with Bash 5.1: `bash: ( - ) / 86400 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ") / 86400 ")`

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Maybe remove the whitespace to `)/86400` does fix it?

Comment: Sorry, it appears I pasted the wrong error message. The real problem is that on macOS, `date -d` sets the kernel's value for daylight saving time. It does not accept a date in that position.

Comment: Maybe use `-jf` instead? If it works, I would add that variant to my answer. Initally I posted my answer because most of the others didn´t explain why they use certain parameters. Also the info about DST I referenced in the link was not prominent available. So my claim is not to provide a plattform independent solution. But together we can work towards that.

Comment: Concerning MacOS and gdate: coreutils is in [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Just install `brew install coreutils` and you've got gdate. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: This looks identical to the accepted answer from 7 years prior.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the MacOS X / *BSD version for your convenience.

```
$ A="2002-20-10"; B="2003-22-11";
$ echo $(((`date -jf %Y-%d-%m "$B" +%s` - `date -jf %Y-%d-%m "$A" +%s`)/86400))
```

nJoy!

Comment: -bash: ( - )/86400: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ")/86400")

Comment: @cavalcade - that is because you haven't done `A="2002-20-10";
B="2003-22-11"`

Comment: Thanks, despite it works for this particular case, I would suggest using `echo $(((\`date -jf "%Y-%d-%m" "$B" +%s\` - \`date -jf "%Y-%d-%m" "$A" +%s\`)/86400))`, i.e. wrapping both formats and variables into double quotes, otherwise may fail on different date format (e.g. `%b %d, %Y`/`Jul 5, 2017`)

Comment: @RAM237 Thats what I get for not paying attention *headsmack* Well spotted, thanks

Comment: ... Y-d-m? Oh my God. I thought I'd never see the day.

Answer (score 7):

If the option -d works in your system, here's another way to do it. There is a caveat that it wouldn't account for leap years since I've considered 365 days per year.

```
date1yrs=`date -d "20100209" +%Y`
date1days=`date -d "20100209" +%j`
date2yrs=`date +%Y`
date2days=`date +%j`
diffyr=`expr $date2yrs - $date1yrs`
diffyr2days=`expr $diffyr \* 365`
diffdays=`expr $date2days - $date1days`
echo `expr $diffyr2days + $diffdays`
```

Answer (score 5):

Even if you don't have GNU date, you'll probably have Perl installed:

```
use Time::Local;
sub to_epoch {
  my ($t) = @_; 
  my ($y, $d, $m) = ($t =~ /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/);
  return timelocal(0, 0, 0, $d+0, $m-1, $y-1900);
}
sub diff_days {
  my ($t1, $t2) = @_; 
  return (abs(to_epoch($t2) - to_epoch($t1))) / 86400;
}
print diff_days("2002-20-10", "2003-22-11"), "\n";
```

This returns `398.041666666667` -- 398 days and one hour due to daylight savings.

---

The question came back up on my feed. Here's a more concise method using a Perl bundled module

```
days=$(perl -MDateTime -le '
    sub parse_date { 
        @f = split /-/, shift;
        return DateTime->new(year=>$f[0], month=>$f[2], day=>$f[1]); 
    }
    print parse_date(shift)->delta_days(parse_date(shift))->in_units("days");
' $A $B)
echo $days   # => 398
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my working approach using zsh. Tested on OSX:

```
# Calculation dates
## A random old date
START_DATE="2015-11-15"
## Today's date
TODAY=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

# Import zsh date mod
zmodload zsh/datetime

# Calculate number of days
DIFF=$(( ( $(strftime -r %Y-%m-%d $TODAY) - $(strftime -r %Y-%m-%d $START_DATE) ) / 86400 ))
echo "Your value: " $DIFF
```

Result:

```
Your value:  1577
```

Basically, we use [`strftime`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fdatetime-Module) reverse (`-r`) feature to transform our date string back to a timestamp, then we make our calculation.

Answer (score 3):

Command line **bash** solution

```
echo $((($(date +%s -d 20210131)-$(date +%s -d 20210101))/86400)) days
```

will print

```
30 days
```

Answer (score 2):

Using mysql command

```
$ echo "select datediff('2013-06-20 18:12:54+08:00', '2013-05-30 18:12:54+08:00');"  | mysql -N
```

Result: 21

NOTE: Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest i managed to get working on centos 7:

```
OLDDATE="2018-12-31"
TODAY=$(date -d $(date +%Y-%m-%d) '+%s')
LINUXDATE=$(date -d "$OLDDATE" '+%s')
DIFFDAYS=$(( ($TODAY - $LINUXDATE) / (60*60*24) ))

echo $DIFFDAYS
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have datediff command (for example dateutils package in some Linux distributions),

```
datediff 2003-11-22 2002-10-20
```

This gives an integer as number of days (398). The input should conform to some standard date like ISO format: YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1):

I'd submit another possible solution in Ruby. Looks like it's the be smallest and cleanest looking one so far:

```
A=2003-12-11
B=2002-10-10
DIFF=$(ruby -rdate -e "puts Date.parse('$A') - Date.parse('$B')")
echo $DIFF
```

Comment: He is looking for a way in bash.

Comment: There is no portable way to do it in shell itself. All alternatives use particular external programs (i.e. GNU `date` or some scripting language) and I honestly think that Ruby is a *good* way to go here. This solution is very short and does not use any non-standard libraries or other dependencies. In fact, I think that there's a higher chance of having Ruby installed than one would have GNU date installed.

Answer (score 1):

Another Python version:

```
python -c "from datetime import date; print date(2003, 11, 22).toordinal() - date(2002, 10, 20).toordinal()"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the shell functions from http://cfajohnson.com/shell/ssr/ssr-scripts.tar.gz; they work in any standard Unix shell.

```
date1=2012-09-22
date2=2013-01-31
. date-funcs-sh
_date2julian "$date1"
jd1=$_DATE2JULIAN
_date2julian "$date2"
echo $(( _DATE2JULIAN - jd1 ))
```

See the documentation at http://cfajohnson.com/shell/ssr/08-The-Dating-Game.shtml

Answer (score 1):

on unix you should have GNU dates installed.  you do not need to deviate from bash.  here is the strung out solution considering days, just to show the steps.  it can be simplified and extended to full dates.

```
DATE=$(echo `date`)
DATENOW=$(echo `date -d "$DATE" +%j`)
DATECOMING=$(echo `date -d "20131220" +%j`)
THEDAY=$(echo `expr $DATECOMING - $DATENOW`)

echo $THEDAY
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that a month is 1/12 of a year:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function mktm(datespec) {
  split(datespec, q, "-")
  return q[1] * 365.25 + q[3] * 365.25 / 12 + q[2]
}
BEGIN {
  printf "%d\n", mktm(ARGV[2]) - mktm(ARGV[1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
perl -e 'use Date::Calc qw(Delta_Days); printf "%d\n", Delta_Days(2002,10,20,2003,11,22);'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume we rsync Oracle DB backups to a tertiary disk manually. Then we want to delete old backups on that disk. So here is a small bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for backup_dir in {'/backup/cmsprd/local/backupset','/backup/cmsprd/local/autobackup','/backup/cfprd/backupset','/backup/cfprd/autobackup'}
do

    for f in `find $backup_dir -type d -regex '.*_.*_.*' -printf "%f\n"`
    do

        f2=`echo $f | sed -e 's/_//g'`
        days=$(((`date "+%s"` - `date -d "${f2}" "+%s"`)/86400))

        if [ $days -gt 30 ]; then
            rm -rf $backup_dir/$f
        fi

    done

done
```

Modify the dirs and retention period ("30 days") to suit your needs.

Comment: Oracle puts backup sets in Flash Recovery Area using format like 'YYYY_MM_DD' so we delete the underscores for passing it to 'date -d'

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS sierra (maybe from Mac OS X yosemate),

To get epoch time(Seconds from 1970) from a file, and save it to a var:

`` old_dt=`date -j -r YOUR_FILE "+%s"` ``

To get epoch time of current time

`` new_dt=`date -j "+%s"` ``

To calculate difference of above two epoch time

`(( diff = new_dt - old_dt ))`

To check if diff is more than 23 days

`(( new_dt - old_dt > (23*86400) )) && echo Is more than 23 days`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $(date +%d/%h/%y) date_today
echo " The other date is 1970/01/01"
TODAY_DATE="1970-01-01"
BEFORE_DATE=$(date +%d%h%y)
echo "THE DIFFERNS IS " $(( ($(date -d $BEFORE_DATE +%s) - $(date -d $TODAY_DATE +%s)) )) SECOUND
```

use it to get your date today and your sec since the date you want. if you want it with days just divide it with 86400

```
echo $(date +%d/%h/%y) date_today
echo " The other date is 1970/01/01"
TODAY_DATE="1970-01-01"
BEFORE_DATE=$(date +%d%h%y)
echo "THE DIFFERNS IS " $(( ($(date -d $BEFORE_DATE +%s) - $(date -d $TODAY_DATE +%s))/ 86400)) SECOUND
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding the expiration to a set amount of days when generating self-signed certificates, I wanted to have them expire just before the [Y2k38 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) kicks in (on 19 January 2028). But, OpenSSL only allow the expiration to be set using `-days`, which is the number of days from the current date.
I ended up using this:

```sh
openssl req -newkey rsa -new -x509 \
  -days $((( $((2**31)) - $(date +%s))/86400-1)) \
  -nodes -out new.crt -keyout new.key -subj '/CN=SAML_SP/'
```

Answer (score 0):

for zsh    (Only works if dates in the same year)

```
echo $(($(date -d "today" +%j) - $(date -d "08 Jan 2021" +%j) )) days
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using postgresql `psql` command**

```
$ echo "select '2003-2-11'::date - '2002-2-10'::date;" | psql -A -t
```

Result: **`366`**

If you want to display the accompanying unit of time in words, you could use the age function:

```
$ echo "select age('2003-2-11'::date, '2002-2-10'::date);" | psql -A -t
```

Result: **`1 year 1 day`**

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install diffdate
diffdate 10-20-2002 11-22-2003
```

Answer (score 0):

One may encounter issues with local date format. The following worked for me just fine.

```bash
$ START_TIME=$(date --rfc-3339=ns --utc)
$ echo "Starting at $(date --date="$START_TIME")"
$ sleep 5
$ END_TIME=$(date --rfc-3339=ns --utc)
$ TIME_DIFF=$(( $(date --date="$END_TIME" +%s) - $(date --date="$START_TIME" +%s) ))
$ echo "Finished at $(date --date="$END_TIME")"
$ echo "DONE in $(date --date="@$TIME_DIFF" --utc +%T)"
```