# How to find a specific number of a day in a range of dates using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, redhat

I want to search the third Thursday in a range of dates using bash.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=2018-03-23
end=2018-04-22
while ! [[ $start > $end ]]; do
    echo $start
    start=$(date -d "$start+third Thursday" +%F)
done
```

Looks like the last part "$start+third Thursday" is not working well,

But using date alone with 'third Thursday' works:

```
date -d "third Thursday" +%F
```

Comment: Please, read how to [write a Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example a.k.a. MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, make a question or describe any problem you have not been able to solve on your own.

Comment: I have improved my initial question.

Comment: It works because $date is "", and therefore you have `date -d "+third Thursday" +%F`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you need the ``$end`` date? Aren't you just looking for the third Thursday after ``$start``?
And if ``$start`` is a Thursday, do you want the Thursday in three weeks or does the current Thursday count as one Thursday?

Comment: Hi! I need `$end` because I want to search in a range of days, maybe its not necessay but I need the while loop. The `start` always is a Friday, so, dosent count as Thursday.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the difference in days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4946785/608639), [find and number of days range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7339253/608639), [Bash how many days since](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22775108/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

This code finds the third Thurday after a given date.

```
#!/bin/bash
start=2018-04-24
thursdayOfCurrentWeek=$((4-$( date +%u --date $start )))
if [[ $thursdayOfCurrentWeek -ge 0 ]]
then
    date -d "$start + $thursdayOfCurrentWeek days + 2 weeks" +%F
else
    date -d "$start + $thursdayOfCurrentWeek days + 3 weeks" +%F
fi
```

Let's split it up:

```
date +%u --date $start
```

This returns the weekday of `$start` as a number (1 = Monday, ..., 4 = Thursday).

```
$((4-$( date +%u --date $start )))
```

This calculates how many days to add to the `$start` date to get the Thursday of the current week.

```
if [[ $thursdayOfCurrentWeek -ge 0 ]]
```

If the date of the Thursday is today or later this week, then add only 2 weeks to the next Thursday since it's already one of the next 3 Thursdays.

```
date -d "$start + $thursdayOfCurrentWeek days + 2 weeks" +%F
# or
date -d "$start + $thursdayOfCurrentWeek days + 3 weeks" +%F
```

Add to or subtract off the `$start` date the days to get the current week's Thursday and add 2 or 3 weeks depending on when the Thursday of this week is.

If the `$start` date is a Thursday and it shouldn't count as one of the three just replace the if statement by:

```
if [[ $thursdayOfCurrentWeek -gt 0 ]]
```

This is a more general answer (because the start date doesn't have to be a Friday) then what you're looking for, but it also works for your use case.

Hope this helps.

PS You don't need the `$end` date.

EDIT:

If you really want the minimal version if the `$start` is always Friday you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=2018-03-23
date -d "$start - 1 day + 3 weeks" +%F
```

Comment: Thanks, what about something more simple:  `date %F -d "$startdate + 4 weeks next thursday"`

Comment: @user2637202 That simply doesn't work that way. You can't combine ``next Thursday`` with a given date.

Comment: @user2637202 I added a solution for your specific case where the start date is always a Friday.