# Determining durration between dates

Tags: bash, date, duration

I'm still pretty new to programming in BASH and i'm racking my brain on a problem. I'm trying to code a script for my work that would make it easy to calculate a refund on a given package cancelled before it's regular end date. Now the simple stuff like inputs and other such things I'm sure I can figure out with googling and experimentation (though should you choose to help with that I would be most appreciative).

What i'm not sure I could find how to do on my own is a script or set of commands that would be able to calculate the number of days / months between two dates and use that variable to calculate the total ammount of refund. I'll try and explain what I am trying to do here:

Input two dates (MM/DD/YYYY format) and get the difference in months and day, IE 3 months 13 days.

Input Base monthly rate

(Base * # of months) + ((base/30) * # of days) = Ammount customer used

Input how much customer payed - Ammount used = Ammount to be refunded

Then preferably it prints it in a manner that one could use to "show their work"

I know this is a bit much to ask for help with but I really could use a hand with the date calculator.

Thanks for any help in advance!

PS I did do a bit of searching beforehand and I found questions SIMILAR to this but nothing that really fit exactly what I needed.

Comment: See http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/31944-simple-date-time-calulation-bash.html.

Comment: A couple of things. Generally when asking questions on SO, you should have already tried to solve your problem and have code to post showing what you have tried, and what your expected output is. When you are coding something in a new language, be prepared to throw out your first attempt, even if it has the appearance of working. Date math is more easily done in other languages. The best you will be able to do in bash is convert to seconds, perform math, then convert it back.

Comment: A common pattern is to convert all time data to a simple serial format such as the Unix epoch (seconds since midnight, 1970-01-01) and do all internal calculations on those values. Converting back to human-readable for display purposes is then fairly trivial - just remember to keep absolute times (2012-02-18 12:34:56) separate from relative (say, a duration of two weeks).  If you are dealing with time zones, you will want to convert everything to UTC internally, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find difference days between to dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946785/how-to-find-difference-days-between-to-dates)

Answer (score 2):

Using my [dateutils](http://hroptatyr.github.com/dateutils) you could go for

```
ddiff '2010-12-05' '2012-04-10' -f '%mmo %dd'
=>
  16mo 5d
```

Answer (score 0):

In `python`, you can use `datetime.strptime()` method from `datetime` module:

```
$ from=01/25/2011 to=01/30/2012
$ dur=`python -c "from datetime import datetime; print((datetime.strptime('$to', '%m/%d/%Y')-datetime.strptime('$from', '%m/%d/%Y')).days)"`
$ echo $dur
370
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want `days` to be greater than 30, this would do the work in bash:

```
date1="12/20/2011"
date2="02/18/2012"

y1=${date1/*\/*\//}
y2=${date2/*\/*\//}

m1=${date1/\/*\/*/}
m2=${date2/\/*\/*/}

d1=${date1/\/$y1/}
d1=${d1/$m1\//}
d2=${date2/\/$y2/}
d2=${d2/$m2\//}

m=$(( $y2 * 12 - $y1 * 12 + $m2 - $m1 ))
d=$(( $d2 - $d1 ))
test $d -lt 0 && { d=$(( $d + 30 )); m=$(( $m - 1 )); }

echo "$m month(s) and $d day(s)."
```

The date parsing can be simplified with the following if you always have 2 characters for `DD` and `MM`:

```
y1=${date1:6:4}
y2=${date2:6:4}

m1=${date1:0:2}
m2=${date2:0:2}

d1=${date1:3:2}
d2=${date2:3:2}
```

Comment: However, note that it is not simple to do arithmetic on floating point numbers in bash.  A awk solution is coming that might be better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk, you could:

```
date1="12/20/2011"
date2="02/19/2012"
echo -e "$date1\n$date2" | awk -F "/" -v base=15 '
  NR == 1 {m1=$1; d1=$2; y1=$3}
  NR == 2 {m2=$1; d2=$2; y2=$3}
  END{m=12*(y2-y1) + m2-m1; d=d2-d1; m=d<0 ? m-1 : m; d=d<0 ? d+30 : d
    print m " month(s) and " d " day(s)"
    print "refund: " (base*m + (base/30.0)*d) "€"}'
```