# 7zip archieving files that are newer than a specific date

Tags: linux, 7zip

I create 7zip files like this from command line in Linux:

```
#   7za   a   /backup/files.7z   /myfolder
```

After that I want to create another zip file that includes all files inside `/myfolder` that are newer then `dd-mm-YY`.
Is it possible to archieve files with respect to file's last change time ?

(I don't want to update "files.7z" file I need to create another zip file that includes only new files)

Comment: Is this still not possible with 7Zip's parameters? WinRar has have this for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The proposal by Gooseman:

```
# find myfolder -mtime -10 -exec 7za a /backup/newfile.7z {} \;
```

adds all files of each directory tree which got new files since the directory is also new and then adds all new files just archived again.

The following includes only new files but does not store the path names in the archive:

```
# find myfolder -type f -mtime -10 -exec 7za a /backup/newfile.7z {} \;
```

This stores only new files — with path names:

```
# find myfolder -type f -mtime -10 > /tmp/list.txt
# tar -cvf /tmp/newfile.tar -T /tmp/list.txt
# 7za a /backup/newfile.7z /tmp/newfile.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this command:

```
find myfolder -mtime -10 -exec 7za a /backup/newfile.7z {} \;
```

In order to find the number to use by the mtime option you could use some of these answers:
[How to find the difference in days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946785/how-to-find-the-difference-in-days-between-two-dates) In your case it would be the difference between the current date and your custom `dd-mm-YY` (in my example `dd-mm-YY` is 10 days back from now)

From man find:

> **-n     for less than n**
>
> **-mtime n**
>
> File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification times.