# Difference between 2 timestamps in hours in korn shell

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a timestamp variable in YYYYYMMDDHHMMSS format. using this variable i need to keep checking in a loop whether time elapsed more than say 1 hour.

the variable is actually in a format like this `123-20150925084520` where i need to extract the second part as timestamp and then compare with current timestamp to see the number of hours. something like `datediff($date1,$date2,"h")`

Here is what i tried. Logged into PUTTY and under 
username@host:[ahome/username]$ tried below from this [SOPOst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946785/how-to-find-the-difference-in-days-between-two-dates)

```
$ echo $(( ( $(date -ud '2003-08-02 17:24:33' +'%h') - $(date -ud '2003-04-21 22:55:02' +'%h') )/60/60/24 )) days
```

which gives `date : illegal option --d`

i dont see --d option but i removed -ud and tried. gives `date: bad conversion`

Other options are implementing complex logics coming in 10 s of lines of code. it will take days for a unix newbie like me to understand the logic. Any quick help would be appreciated.

Comment: what have  you tried? S.O. isn't a free coding service. You're expected to show your work, preferably as a test case that people can cut/paste into their terminals (in the case of ksh).  You should also include your expected out from the inputs. There are numerous functions posted here on S.O. in ksh that do date calculations. Did you try looking for them? Sorry, but Good luck.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/quickly-calculate-date-differences

Comment: tried this link too. but getting some error. Ended up using unix time to get seconds and subtract it (one of the answers in the same post) to get hours. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution found.

```
    $STARTTIME=20150925061225
    ENDTIME=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')   #20150925090000
    TIMEDIFF=`expr $ENDTIME - $STARTTIME`
    echo $TIMEDIFF # returns 28775(2 hours)
    if [ TIMEDIFF -gt 50000 ];          # Is diff. Greater than 5 hours?
```