# Finding the difference between two time stamp with date in it

Tags: shell

I would like to get a simple shell script to find the difference in two times.

**Example:**

Tue May  9 10:38:17 BST 2017

-rw-rw-r--    1 unikix   unikix         1387 Feb 17 11:34 ABC

The first one is the system date and other one, the time extracted from output of list command.

There is a need to check the time format also (12 hour clock and 24 clock) before finding the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the difference in days between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946785/how-to-find-the-difference-in-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DATE1="Tue May 9 10:38:17 BST 2017"
DATE2="Feb 17 11:34"

sec1=$(date --date "${DATE1}" +"%s")
sec2=$(date --date "${DATE2}" +"%s")

diff=$((${sec1} - ${sec2}))

echo "Difference is ${diff} sec"
```

Comment: Since, I am using AIX (an IBM version of unix), the option --date is not working. Please find the error below. Could you please help me in this.






sec1=$(date --date "${DATE1}" +"%s")

date: illegal option -- -

Usage: date [-u] [+Field Descriptors]