# Calculate distance between today and next recurring date in the month using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, date, distance, lte

I have a subscription to a LTE service that expires the same day each month. For example, if I paid the first time on the 8th of Feb, it will expire on the 8th of Mar, Apr, etc., so it is not a 28 days based subscription, but the distance between two occurrences is variable.

Now, I need to write a shell script in order to calculate the distance (in days, or maybe days + hours) from today to the next recurring deadline, taking in account that each month is different.

I am thinking to use cal command, but I do not know how to do it.
I need to place the result in a variable (inside a bash script that is already done but working with fixed 28 days subscription), in order to recalculate the remaining bandwidth and trim it accordingly.

Comment: This website is intended for software developers. Show your code and describe what didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the difference in days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946785/how-to-find-the-difference-in-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: If today is November 8, do you want the output to be zero or 30?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $days_diff will be an integer (i.e. no decimals)

```
days_diff=$(( (`date -d $B +%s` - `date -d "00:00" +%s`) / (24*3600) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to glenn! your solution seems good. 
In the meantime, I also found this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

_day_today=$(date +%d)
_recur_day=8
_days_in_month=$(cal | grep -E -v '[A-Za-z]' | wc -w)

if [ "$_recur_day" -gt "$_day_today" ]
then
  substraction=$((_recur_day-_day_today))
else
  substraction=$((_recur_day+_days_in_month-_day_today))
fi

echo "$_days_in_month"
echo "$substraction"
```

However, now I realized that this in not enough: I also need to know how to calculate how many days elapsed from last occurrence, and to do this I need to know how many days were in the previous month. 
How do I check how many days in previous month?

Comment: All of this should be in the question.

Answer (score -1):

With bash version 4.3, the builtin `printf` can [format a datetime](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf). Still need GNU date to parse a timestamp though. Here, I'm using `%j` to get the day of the year: that makes it easy to get the days remaining.

```sh
days_remaining() {
    local day month year doy renew_day=8
    read day month year doy < <(printf '%(%-d %-m %Y %j)T\n' -1)
    if ((day >= renew_day)) && ((++month > 12)); then
        month=1
        ((year++))
    fi
    echo $(( $(date -d "$year-$month-$renew_day" '+%j') - doy ))
}

echo "There are $(days_remaining) days until next renewal"
```

Today, the 16th of November, it's 22 days remaining. If today is November 8, it will output 30 days.

---

Here's another implementation that does not require any external tools:

```sh
days_remaining() {
    local timestamp days renew_day=8
    for ((
        timestamp=$(printf '%(%s)T' -1), days = 0; 
        $(printf '%(%-d)T' $timestamp) != renew_day;
        days++, timestamp += 86400
    )); do :; done
    echo $days
}
```

If today is November 8, it will output 0 days.

---

And the days since the last renewal:

```sh
days_since() {
    local timestamp days renew_day=8
    for ((
        timestamp=$(printf '%(%s)T' -1) - 86400, days=1;
        $(printf '%(%-d)T' $timestamp) != renew_day;
        days++, timestamp -= 86400
    )); do :; done
    echo $days
}
```

---

or combine them:

```sh
dom() { printf '%(%-d)T' "$1"; }
days() {
    local now=$(printf '%(%s)T' -1)
    local renew_day=8
    local used=1 left=0 ts
    for ((ts = now - 86400; $(dom $ts) != renew_day; used++, ts -= 86400)); do :; done
    for ((ts = now;         $(dom $ts) != renew_day; left++, ts += 86400)); do :; done
    echo "$used $left"
}
```

Today, that function outputs `8 22`
If the renew_day is 16, it will output `31 0`

Answer (score -1):

Will require some tweaking to adjust for desired output when today is the day of, or day before, expiry.

```
expiry=8

# get expiry this month and next month, in format: YYYY-MM-DD
exp_this_month=$(date +%Y-%m-$expiry)
exp_next_month=$(date --date="$exp_this_month +1 month" +%Y-%m-%d)

# get these dates in seconds
exp_this_month_sec=$(date --date="$exp_this_month" +%s)
exp_next_month_sec=$(date --date="$exp_next_month" +%s)

# calculate offset to next expiry, by subtracting
# the seconds-representation of dates
today=$(date +%s)

if [ $today -lt $exp_this_month_sec ] ; then
    echo $(( ( $exp_this_month_sec - $today ) / (24*3600) ))
else
    echo $(( ( $exp_next_month_sec - $today ) / (24*3600) ))
fi
```