# Get timestamp difference linux command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Iam having start time and endtime in below formart

```
endDatetime="12:53:12.846539"
startDatetime="12:53:12.219691"
```

Using below command iam trying to find the difference of timestamp in seconds..but getting invalid date

```
 expr $(date -d "$startDatetime" +%s) - $(date -d "$endDatetime" +%s)
date: invalid date '12:53:12.846539'
date: invalid date '12:53:12.219691
```

Another way tried

```
 date -d "12:53:12.846539" +%s
date: invalid date '12:53:12.846539'
```

Using linux command how i can get the time difference in above format in seconds

Comment: Convert the times themselves into seconds-since-epoch; then getting the difference in seconds is just subtraction. (That said, note that neither `expr` nor built-in shell math -- and in modern times, you should be using built-in math, not expr -- supports floating-point; so you'll need to truncate to the prior second boundary).

Comment: Your timestamps include sub-second precision, which the standard date command in most Linux distributions doesn't handle out-of-the-box. However, you can still calculate the difference using some string manipulations and arithmetic.

Comment: @JJY9, the arithmetic is tricky. Better to just do the truncation then use `date` if your shell is too old.

Comment: (`startDatetimeTrunc=${startDatetime%.*}`)

Comment: ...but of course that won't work when there's less than a second of difference. You need floating-point-aware tools then; think about awk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the difference in days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946785/how-to-find-the-difference-in-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

#### What I would do using shell tools:

```
printf '%s\n' "$endDatetime" "$startDatetime" |
    xargs -I{} date -d "{}" "+%s%N" |
    paste -sd '-' | bc
```

`%N` are nanoseconds.

#### Output

```
626848000
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your time in microsecond precision. So you are more or less on the right track but need to specify the correct date format.

Sample code:

```
endDatetime="12:53:12.846539"
startDatetime="12:53:12.219691"

endDatetimeMicros=$(date -d $endDatetime "+%s%6N")
startDatetimeMicros=$(date -d $startDatetime "+%s%6N")

result=$((endDatetimeMicros - startDatetimeMicros))

echo $result
```

Difference in microseconds: 626848

To convert microseconds to seconds in bash this is a useful printf command:

```
printf "%.3f\n" $(bc <<< "scale=3; $result / 1000000")
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a great way to compute time differences using basic UNIX tools. Computation involving dates easily gets tricky with leap years and leap seconds, and so on, it's really best to use proper programming libraries that are explicitly built to handle all that complexity.

You can do this for example with Python, and hopefully it still falls within your definition of "linux tools".

This Python one-liner takes the start and end times in the format in your example, and prints their difference in *seconds*:

`python3 -c 'import sys; _, start, end = sys.argv; from datetime import datetime; format = "%H:%M:%S.%f"; delta = datetime.strptime(end, format) - datetime.strptime(start, format); print(delta.microseconds)' "12:53:12.219691" "12:53:12.846539"`

The output is an unspectacular 0 since the difference in the posted example is less than a second.

You may want to print seconds *and* microseconds, by changing `print(delta.microseconds)` to `print(f"{delta.seconds}.{delta.microseconds}")`.

To print in some other formats or other details, adjust the `print` statement.

Comment: I'm not so worried about leap years and leap seconds here -- the translation to epoch time takes care of that. It's needing microsecond resolution that's a problem using the shell in the OP's case.